# Laravel - How to authenticate admin and users separately

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I have 2 separate controls for my website.

- Operators
- Users

I want to authenticate users from 2 different tables for my application. Like if user if on `myapplication.com/admin` it should be authenticated from **tbl_operators** and if the user if on `myapplication.com` it should be authenticated from **tbl_users**

How to achieve this functionality in `Laravel 5.2`

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the Auth built in with Laravel then this may not be possible. However if you wanna build your own authentication specifically for the admin then this may be possible.

You could also look into storing in an entirely new database using

```
DB::connection('name')
```